# Add a switch case inside case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

In my android app, i have an actvity with different number inside a linear layout per number. Each linear layout has an onClick method  that call a method in the activity to show a dialog before call the number,  and if button YES is choosen, an intent action_call starts.

Here is my xml file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:id="@+id/ln_u">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ps_u"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_call"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="123456"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:id="@+id/ln_r">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ps_r"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_call"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="123456"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:id="@+id/ln_t">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ps_t"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_call"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="123456"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
...
```

In the activity i added the method "onClick" with the Dialog for "yes/no" calling, and for one number it works properly.

That is the part of the main for the dialog and the onClick method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Call the number?   ")
                //.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_alert)
                .setTitle("Call")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", this)
                .setNegativeButton("No", this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();

        ad.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE: // yes
                        String number = "123456";
                        Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE: // no
                break;
            default:
                // nothing
                break;
        }
    }
```

What i want to achieve is the possibility to add another Switch/case method into the "case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:" that take the id of the different linear layout, and for each id, call the relative number with the intent call_action.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Brus

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this out but why not a static method that gets a AlertDialog like this:

```
public static AlertDialog getCallPhoneAlertDialog(final Context context, final String phoneNumber) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("CALL")
    .setMessage("CALL THE NUMBER? " + phoneNumber)
    .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, call);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).create();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In this method i will miss a View and get error when using it. I get of course this in my logcat:     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.brusasu.ursula55.ActivityProntoSoccorso for onClick handler on view class android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'ln_u'

Comment: Call it from an external class and pass in context and phone number.  No need for the activity to implement  DialogInterface.OnClickListener